# How to reuse a placeholder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to reuse a placeholder for different shapes of input but failed. And I search for the answer on the Internet while I only found that how to reuse variables by variable_scope("",reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE). I try the same method while it didn't work. Python throw an exception "ValueError: Duplicate node name in graph: 'input_image'". I'm confused and thanks for the help in advance.

For example, I want to train a net with pictures in 128*128 and I want to test the net with pictures in 1080*960:

```
        with tf.variable_scope('test/', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
            input_image = tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size, 128, 128, 3], dtype=tf.float32, name='input_image/')
        aug_image= train_net(input_image)
        sess = tf.Session()
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)
        for i in range(100000):
           augg = sess.run([aug_image],feed_dict={input_image: tmp})
           if i % 1000 == 0:
               with tf.variable_scope('test/', reuse=True):
                   input_image = tf.placeholder(shape=[1, 1080, 960, 3],dtype=tf.float32,name='input_image/')
                   aug = sess.run([aug_image],{input_image: pic1})
                   show(aug)
```

Comment: Usually when you are not sure the size of a placeholder you just put `None` in its place. Then in your code if you need to reshape, just put the other dimensions there and use the `-1` to infer the dimension of that `None`, or you can  pass it in in the `feed_dict` as well.

Comment: @DocDriven I've post the simplified code. Actually, I use two programs to implement showing the result, while I still do not know how to use two kinds of placeholders with the same name.

Comment: @KevinHe I know I should use None if I do not have the exact shape of the placeholder. The problem is that I use get_shape in my train net so I have to set the shape of the tensor. By the way, tf.shape is helpless because I could not  get the exact parameter when I build the net.